# Updated launch image sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen, image-size, launchimage

I need to find out the proper sizes and the file names for all these launch images.

[image]

[image]

Latest Xcode versions doesn't show the expected sizes in the attributed inspector when you select those slots. And Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/) on launch images isn't much use either.

Answer (score 4):

HERE AN IMAGE THAT SHOWS THE SIZE'S CORRESPONDENCES :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xszm9.png

And a text version for everyone that doesn’t like graphical solutions:

- **320 x 480 px**

  - iPhone Portrait iOS 5,6 1x
- **640 x 960 px**

  - iPhone Portrait iOS 7, 8 2x
  - iPhone Portrait iOS 5, 6 2x
- **640 x 1136 px**

  - iPhone Portrait iOS 7, 8 Retina 4
  - iPhone Portrait iOS 5, 6 Retina 4
- **750 x 1334 px**

  - iPhone Portrait iOS 8 Retina HD 4.7
- **1242 x 2208 px**

  - iPhone Portrait iOS 8 Retina HD 5.5
- **2208 x 1242 px**

  - iPhone Landscape iOS 8 Retina HD 5.5
- **768 x 1024 px**

  - iPad Portrait iOS 7, 8 1x
  - iPad Portrait iOS 5, 6 1x
- **1536 x 2048 px**

  - iPad Portrait iOS 7, 8 2x
  - iPad Portrait iOS 5, 6 2x
- **1024 x 768 px**

  - iPad Landscape iOS 7, 8 1px
  - iPad Landscape iOS 5, 6 1px
- **2048 x 1536 px**

  - iPad Landscape iOS 7, 8 2px
  - iPad Landscape iOS 5, 6 2px
- **768 x 1004 px**

  - iPad Portrait Without Status Bar iOS 5, 6 1px
- **1536 x 2008 px**

  - iPad Portrait Without Status Bar iOS 5, 6 2px
- **1024 x 748 px**

  - iPad Landscape Without Status Bar iOS 5, 6 1px
- **2048 x 1496 px**

  - iPad Landscape Without Status Bar iOS 5, 6 2px

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation anymore, but I found this list here [here](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html)

Anyway, I suggest you take a look at using a storyboard as launch screen, thereby you're independent of the screen sizes. There you can also include e.g. images.

[image: Launch image screen size iPhone and iPad]

Comment: can you mark this as correct answer if it solved your problem please?